Problem of Induction in Methodology of History?
Has there been any work done in exploring how the problem of induction applies to the study of history?
It seems to me that many historical inferences might require a sort of uniformity of human/societal nature, so I’m looking for any discussion on this. Note that this is not about the history of philosophy, but rather the philosophy of history.

I don't know if my comment is helpful. It is not about induction per se. When I studied law I decided that events occur (stuff happens) and humans invent stories. Events happen and there are witnesses. The facts are only supported by the testimony of a witness (I took this gun from the murder scene and locked it in the evidence locker and here it is at trial). The lawyers on each side of a dispute, for example, try to argue for distinct sets of facts, and if the facts are not easy to dispute, then they argue alternative stories of events. Historians do something similar with historical events.

@SystemTheory In your example, induction is being used as assumptions are made about how human generally invent stories based on events, and say, how people treat their own testimony as a witness. Doubting testimonies in court because of the problem of induction seems too radical, but I think doubting historical inference based on PoI is less problematic, especially if the inference spans centuries or even millennia. I guess I don't have very concrete examples in mind, but maybe inferences that involves genre of texts, intention of authors, etc.

John Guarnaschelli (https://youtu.be/C6Qpsw71MDM?list=PLGi1tdpNGex65sAw-lgjXNM3mm1qXL9ky&t=240) and I were friends from 1999-2006. His first career was a history of war professor. I once asked about this career. He said, "I created a parent for myself. I did something I enjoyed and the money showed up in my bank account." John invented the courses he wanted to teach. This was a Freudian slip because John walked this back when I asked him about it in his role as therapist. Is the therapist creating a parent for himself? John maps history and psychotherapy to personal narratives (storytelling).

In this video John Guarnaschelli discusses his epistemology (knowledge) of psychotherapy and compares it to the epistemology (knowledge) of medicine versus the epistemology (knowledge) of history: https://youtu.be/-9DSEBmRl7A?list=PLGi1tdpNGex65sAw-lgjXNM3mm1qXL9ky. Sigmund Freud argues that every son wants to kill the father and marry the mother, even if this desire is repressed or suppressed into the unconscious, and I suppose this is a highly questionable Problem of Induction. My idea of therapy is unfortunate persons suffer in their drama and feel compelled to pay for social intercourse.
